# Change CSS class after scrolling 1000px down

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, fixed

I want a fixed menu to appear in the left column of my site once the user scrolls 1000px down, but am not very experienced with jQuery/JS.  I thought something like this would work but it isn't doing anything:

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">[MENU_WILL_GO_HERE]</div>
```

STYLE:

```
#menu{display:none;}​
```

JQ:

```
var fixed = false;
 ​$(document).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ) {
        if( !fixed ) {
           fixed = true;
           $('#menu').css({position:'fixed', display:'block'});
        }
        } else {
           if( fixed ) {
               fixed = false;
               $('#menu').css({display:'none'});
        } 
    } 
});​
```

Q:

Is there a reason this doesn't work? The code is an example on http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/psvn9/1/, and even when I copy/paste that example exactly as it is into a blank html page, with a link of the latest jquery library, it still doesn't work like it does on that jsfiddle page. What could I be overlooking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your braces are wrong in your example, but regardless, you can simplify your code:

**CSS**:

```
#menu {
    display : none;
    position : fixed;
}
```

**JS**:

```
 $(document).scroll(function() {
    $('#menu').toggle($(this).scrollTop()>1000)
 });​
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/h3qyV/1/

Comment: Even shorter: `$('#menu').toggle($(this).scrollTop()>1000)`. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/h3qyV/1/

Comment: Ah good old toggle how did I neglect you? Honestly forgot it took a bool param. Good catch, friend.

Comment: This does exactly what I want but I can't get the script to execute on any page. Does it need to be in a certain <script></script> tag or be before or after the HTML code? I can't figure out why it's not executing and it's the exact same code from the fiddle.

Comment: @ZackTaylor: yes. You need to put `<script type="text/javascript"> your code </script >`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this

```
if( $(this).scrollTop() > 1000 )
```

you are looking for 1000px scroll,but it appears 100px due to this,from your code