# Change CSS class after scrolling 100% screen height down

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm making a single page website and i want to show nav-menu on second part till end. I found this question:
[Change CSS class after scrolling 1000px down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470645/change-css-class-after-scrolling-1000px-down)

...and i used the answer of **AlienWebguy**

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $('#menu').toggle($(this).scrollTop()>1000)
});​
```

But i don't want to do 1000px. I want to use it 100% of screen that it can change with different platforms or resolution.

Do you know what can i do?

Comment: Just find out how big the screen is, and use that instead of 1000

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change CSS class after scrolling 1000px down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470645/change-css-class-after-scrolling-1000px-down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#menu').toggle($(this).scrollTop()>windowHeight)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `1000` with `$(window).height()`

As in:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $('#menu').toggle($(this).scrollTop()>$(window).height())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that :

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())){
        //here, you're at the bottom of the page
        console.log("BOTTOM");
    } else {
        //here, you're not arrived yet
    }
});
```

it will work for every screen size, in theory.